# Read excel file with blanks to Junit Tests

Tags: java, junit, parameterized, import-from-excel

I need help to alter the class I'm using to read an excel for unit Parameterized Test class. Your help is much appreciated.

The below class does not read blank cell values. It skips the blank cells, so the number of arguments passed to the constructor is wrong. I need the constructor to accept null values when the cell values are blank.

```
public class SpreadsheetData {

    /**
     * The contents of the spreadsheet, in a form compatible with JUnit 4 parameterized tests.
     */
    private transient Collection<Object[]> data = null;

    public SpreadsheetData(final InputStream excelInputStream) throws IOException {
        this.data = loadFromSpreadsheet(excelInputStream);
    }

    public Collection<Object[]> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    private Collection<Object[]> loadFromSpreadsheet(final InputStream excelFile)
            throws IOException {
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

        data = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        int numberOfColumns = countNonEmptyColumns(sheet);


        List<Object[]> rows = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        List<Object> rowData = new ArrayList<Object>();


        int numberOfRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        //for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (int y=1;y<numberOfRows;y++){
            Row row=sheet.getRow(y);
            if (isEmpty(row)) {
                break;
            } else {
                rowData.clear();
                for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(column);
                    rowData.add(objectFrom(workbook, cell));
                }
                rows.add(rowData.toArray());
            }
        }

        return rows;
    }

    private boolean isEmpty(final Row row) {
        Cell firstCell = row.getCell(0);
        boolean rowIsEmpty = (firstCell == null)
                || (firstCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
        return rowIsEmpty;
    }

    /**
     * Count the number of columns, using the number of non-empty cells in the
     * first row.
     */
    private int countNonEmptyColumns(final Sheet sheet) {
        Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(1);
        return firstEmptyCellPosition(firstRow);
    }

    private int firstEmptyCellPosition(final Row cells) {
        int columnCount = 0;
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                break;
            }
            columnCount++;
        }
        return columnCount;
    }


    private Object objectFrom(final HSSFWorkbook workbook, final Cell cell) {
        Object cellValue = null;

        if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            cellValue = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            cellValue = getNumericCellValue(cell);
        } else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
            cellValue = cell.getBooleanCellValue();
        } else if (cell.getCellType()  ==Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
            cellValue = evaluateCellFormula(workbook, cell);
        }

        return cellValue;

    }

    private Object getNumericCellValue(final Cell cell) {
        Object cellValue;
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
            cellValue = new Date(cell.getDateCellValue().getTime());
        } else {
            cellValue = cell.getNumericCellValue();
        }
        return cellValue;
    }

    private Object evaluateCellFormula(final HSSFWorkbook workbook, final Cell cell) {
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper()
                .createFormulaEvaluator();
        CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
        Object result = null;

        if (cellValue.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
            result = cellValue.getBooleanValue();
        } else if (cellValue.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            result = cellValue.getNumberValue();
        } else if (cellValue.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            result = cellValue.getStringValue();   
        }
          else if (cellValue.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
          {
              result =cellValue.getStringValue();; 
          }


        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: *Comment from [Ria](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4652967/ria)*: I'm not sure whether I got your question right. As far as I see, you stop reading data by ending the loop with a "break" if the cell is blank (isEmpty checks if the first cell in row is blank). Is this your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the loadFromSpreadsheet function by implementing the MissingCellPolicy.

```
 for (int column = 0; column < numberOfColumns; column++) {
                Cell cell = row.getCell(column, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                rowData.add(objectFrom(workbook, cell));
            }
```